# C++ -- float*** avoidance

Tags: c++, c, arrays, list, arguments

I am to convert some custom data structures into float** and pass them as arguments of a method that is dealing with float** only.

In my first version, method takes only 2 float** as arguments, so that i easily have

```
MyClass::MyMethod(float** data1, float** data2){}
```

In a second version, I would like to vehicle a list of float** with length varying from one execution to the next.

I only have float*** as a solution, which is not nice at all.

MyMethod is C-stylish, I don't want any vector, etc...

Other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you won't use the standard library, what's the point in using C++?

Comment: If you want a dynamic array that holds `float**`, you're going to be [a three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) and use `float***`. I'd suggest rethinking your API or your avoidance of the tools C++ provides you with.

Comment: @Cornstalks tell the 200 others working this way on that project

Comment: @antitrust: I would love to :) But really, as I said, if you want a dynamic array that holds `float**`, you really are going to have to use `float***`. The only other alternative to having a dynamic array of `float**` is to use some kind of container (like `vector`) (which just hides the `float***`-ness), but apparently that's not an option.

Comment: *"I don't want to write C++ that looks like C and I don't want to use any C++ features either."* <- Makes absolutely no sense.  You're apparently looking for an answer which does not exist.

Comment: _snarky comment_: use a `typedef` ;)

Comment: I have issues believing that 200 people in a **C++** project would like `float***` over a higher level container... Are you working in **C**? (I am also a bit amused that 200 people are working in the same project in a way that a change to one function interface would affect all those users, and if that is the case simplifying the interface is even more of an advantage... Are you sure of what your **real** requirements are?)

Comment: David, you have worked on a 200 person project? As a minion? I think that the negative comments antitrust is getting here are way out of line. He's working within constraints, for all we know he's campaigning to change them, but right now he has a problem and is trying to find the least bad option within those constraints. If he had phrased the question with no mention of C++ it would have been a completely reasonable question.Kudos to him for trying to find a clean solution rather than the first thing that might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a struct containing some float**. You could even pass in an instance of the struct.

It means that the called function doesn't directly manipulate the caller's float** which I think is cleaner.

We're solving this as C programmers, I understand that sometimes we're constrained not to use true C++ techniques.

If you have (apologies for any syntax errors it's years since I wrote C)

```
 struct floatCarrier { float **ppFloat1, float **ppFloat2 } 
 typdef FloatCarrier struct floatCarrier
```

Your interface now can be

```
 FloatCarrier myMethod (FloatCarrier in)  /* passed by value, as an example */
```

the implementation of myMethod can work with the float** from the input FloatCarrier. If it needs to modify the arrays then it creates a new FloatCarrier with new float** instances and when it has finished it returns the new FloatCarrier. This does put some responsibility with the caller to grab the new float** from the returned struct, but somehow I like that, feels cleaner.

As to whether you should have a known number of members or an array ... well your example had exactly 2 parameters, so the struct would have two members, but you can have an array or anything you like.

How does it solve your problem: you no longer need to change your caller's float** hence no float***. We use a struct as a function can return only one value, so we package up the results into a single object.

Comment: but... my struct should have a known number of float** members, ... or a list of float** which is a float**... how does this fix the problem i mention ?

Comment: @antitrust: I *think* what djna meant was to have some `struct MyStruct { float** data; };` (or perhaps something with a proper interface) and instead have an array of `MyStruct`s instead of an array of raw `float**`s.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not `float***` (or `float**&`) but how do you come to that: what do that `float**` represent?
If they are representing something, give that something a "name" and a "scope" to live in in. In other word, create a "class" and let the class to manage the * one at time. Otherwise whatever code you can do will look arcane.

There is no point in using C++ if all the code reduces to manipulate single variables through a number of explicit indirection.

Although solutions in the "two star word" can be found, try thinking if it is not he case to restructure the code to make it more scalable.